# SQLNavigator Turning Creating Type and Function and using it to parse

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-navigator

Currently this is how I am using this function:

```
TYPE                       strings IS TABLE OF VARCHAR(255) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
str_columns                strings;

function parse ( prc_string   in varchar,
                prc_delim    in varchar ) return strings as

  str_record    varchar(32767) := '';
  str_field     varchar(255)   := '';
  int_length    integer        := 0;
  int_sub       integer        := 0;
  int_count     integer        := 0;

  str_fields    strings;

  begin
     str_record := trim(prc_string) || prc_delim;
     int_length := length(str_record);
     if int_length = 0 then
        int_count := -1;
        return str_fields;
     end if;

     loop
        int_sub := int_sub + 1;
        exit when int_sub > int_length;
        if substr(str_record,int_sub,1) <> prc_delim then
           str_field := str_field || substr(str_record,int_sub,1);
        else
           int_count := int_count + 1;
           str_fields(int_count) := str_field;
           str_field := '';
        end if;
     end loop;

     return str_fields;

  end;

  str_columns            :=  parse_function(inp_buffer, ',');
```

I need to be able to make this into a Function, and call it from many procedures. It parses text with a comma delimiter. I tried using Collection Type and Function in SQL Navigator but I received the error expression is of wrong type.

Essentially this procedure opens a text file and parses it.